# Lines density in each grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh, density-plot

I have multiple lines within region where x= 104.3 to 105 and y= 29.3 to 29.7.
I want to divide the map into smaller grid sizes (0.001*0.002) to convert like points and plot the point density (line) in each grid using colormesh.
I have done some tests using the below dataset but it seems like it also shows the density where no lines are crossing.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# map range and grid size
x_min, x_max = 104.4, 104.9
y_min, y_max = 29.3, 29.7
grid_size = 0.001

# grid of x and y coordinates
x = np.arange(x_min, x_max, grid_size)
y = np.arange(y_min, y_max, grid_size)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

density_grid = np.zeros_like(X)

# demo lines (start and end points)
lines = [
    [(104.42, 29.32), (104.45, 29.6)],
    [(104.48, 29.31), (104.69, 29.32)],
    [(104.47, 29.5), (104.89, 29.42)],
    [(104.41, 29.33), (104.45, 29.5)],
    [(104.43, 29.34), (104.47, 29.48)],
]

# Iterate through each line and update density grid
for line in lines:
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
    indices = np.where((x1 <= X) & (X <= x2) & (y1 <= Y) & (Y <= y2))
    density_grid[indices] += 1

# Plotting the map, density grid, and lines
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X, Y, color='black', marker='.')
mesh = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, density_grid, cmap='hot', shading='auto')
for line in lines:
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = line
    ax.plot([x1, x2], [y1, y2], color='blue')

plt.colorbar(mesh, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]